# PedService block from Pedestrian Library do not have option of using ResourcePool

Tags: simulation, anylogic

**I am using pedestrian library.**

- Agents are going to a service and its fine but I want to use Resourcepool so I can set the workers for the service.
  [image: process flow l]
- I also tried using Process Modeling library service but the agents then don't follow the attractors when they reach to the service node.

[image]

See not following the attractors standing randomly

[image]

I want to use resourcepool but the agents should also stand on the attractors when they are in the service.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will work for you, you can't setup the number of resources since a service point is the resource, but you can enable/disable the servicepoints with this

```
servicePoint.setSuspended(true);
```